# "bool operator<(const MyStruct& m) const" to Java

Tags: java, c++

I have this bool operator inside a struct called MyStruct but I don't know how to convert this to Java. In my Java class I have those three variables but thats not important here. Any tips? Thanks.

```
bool operator<(const MyStruct& m) const {
        if(sadness != m.sadness) return sadness < m.sadness;
        if(effort != m.effort) return effort > m.effort;
        return happiness > m.happiness;
    }
```

UPDATE: I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Java does not have operator overloading. You should define a method.

Comment: Java has no operator overloading, you can however invent your own function to do the comparison.

Comment: Implement `Comparable` or a create custom `Comparator`.

Comment: There is no operator overloading in Java. You can implement a Comparator and then check `if (comparator.compare(a,b)<0)` instead of `if (a<b)`.

Comment: You could try something like Java-oo (https://github.com/amelentev/java-oo) or manually implement the compareTo() method

Comment: It seems to me that implementing `Comparable<MyStruct>` will come closer to the idea in you C++ operator. Use your search engine and find overwhelmingly many examples.

Comment: Thank you! I will do it.